# Dynamically Show UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

**Solved**:

Phillip Mills' solution has solved the issue presented in this post, as outlined below.

---

Currently, when a user searches for a beer in the application, the beer shows up in a `UITableViewCell` subclass, which displays the name of the beer and the brewery name in `UILabel` instances. The cell also contains four buttons below the labels: `likeButton`, `tryButton`, `dislikeButton`, and `deleteButton`.

When a user searches the API database for a beer, the user can then save a beer to a specific category in Core Data by using one of the buttons in the cell. These saved beers will then show up in a `UITableView` elsewhere in the app. I am able to successfully save and delete beers from the cells, and they do show up in the correct category's `UITableView` instance. However, if a returned beer result is **not** saved in Core Data, I want the `deleteButton` to not be shown in the cell that is populated from the JSON of the API because the app is set up for the user to save a beer, change a beer's category, or delete a beer from the search results `UITableView` instance.

I have the saving, changing of a beer's category, and deleting of a beer working correctly in both the category `UITableView` instances and in the search results `UITableView`. My issue arises when displaying the buttons in the results `UITableView`.

When results are returned from he API, I only want the `deleteButton` to be displayed if there is a beer saved in Core Data that matches the returned result. I'm guessing that I need to perform this comparison in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but I feel like I am going about it incorrectly because I can get the `deleteButton` to either be visible or be hidden in all cells, regardless of whether the beer is saved in Core Data or not.

Here is my current implementation:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if scopeButtonIndex == 0 {

        let beerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("foundBeerResultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BeerTableViewCell

        let beer = foundBeerResults[indexPath.row]
        beerCell.beerNameLabel.text = beer.name
        beerCell.breweryNameLabel.text = beer.brewery
        beerCell.delegate = self

        for savedBeer in savedBeers {
            if beer.name == savedBeer.beerName && beer.brewery == savedBeer.beerBrewery {
                beerCell.deleteButton.hidden = false

            } else if beer.name != savedBeer.beerName && beer.brewery != savedBeer.beerBrewery {
                beerCell.deleteButton.hidden = true
            }
        } 
        return beerCell
    }
}
```

Currently `savedBeers` in an array of the saved beers in Core Data. As you can see, I am taking each beer that is returned from the API and saved in `foundBeerResults`, which populates the results `UITableView` instance. I am then looping through `savedBeers` to see if each returned beer in `foundBeerResults` matches the saved beer. If the information matches, I want the `deleteButton` to be visible so that the user can delete the saved beer directly from the search results. If a returned beer result does not match a currently saved beer, I want the `deleteButton` to be invisible.

Am I incorrect by assuming that I should not be iterating through arrays in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? It seems inefficient. However, I am not sure of how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping might or might not be a performance problem.  You can measure for that but let's assume "not" for the moment since it seems like that would be a fairly small array you're using.

I think your problem is that you're not stopping the loop once you get a right answer.

How about:

```
   beerCell.deleteButton.hidden = true
   for savedBeer in savedBeers {
        if beer.name == savedBeer.beerName && beer.brewery == savedBeer.beerBrewery {
            beerCell.deleteButton.hidden = false
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same behavior after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: What is the content of `savedBeers` just before you start the loop?

Comment: Ah! That was the issue! I was not fetching the saved beers and putting them into `savedBeers` when the view appeared. I have updated the original post. Much appreciated!